# when updating nodeJs gives "ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600" error

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to update my node using following command

```
npm cache clean -f
npm install -g n
n stable
```

while running second command it gives following error

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "n"
npm ERR! node v0.12.0
npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1
npm ERR! code EBADPLATFORM

npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@2.0.2
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://github.com/tj/n) of module `n`:

> Note: Does not work on Windows at the moment. Pull Requests are appreciated.

So, they do not support windows OS as of now. And the same issue is reported by the module also when you are trying to install on your machine. Please refer to your error-stack-trace. I am outlining the relevant error-stack-trace as below for your reference:

```
npm ERR! notsup Unsupported
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: n@2.0.2
npm ERR! notsup Valid OS:    !win32
npm ERR! notsup Valid Arch:  any
npm ERR! notsup Actual OS:   win32
npm ERR! notsup Actual Arch: x64
```

---

Please install the latest node executables for windows from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/). And this should help you upgrade node on your system.